# IP Addresses not showing up in Facebook login history

Tags: ip, facebook

A few of my husbands friends (we believe) have been logging into his Facebook and messenger. They are in the Netherlands and we live in the US, however, he used to live there and they know his password. But when we check the log in history, only my local IP addresses show up.

Is there a way they can hide their IP address? Does Facebook only show most used IP addresses? How can we find out for sure?

Comment: I think your husband should definitely enable 2FA for Facebook login. Also change the password, and if the password is used in other services as well, change them too.

Comment: We definitely learned our lesson. Is there a way to find the locations in Europe his account was logged in at? Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Honestly, I don't know. Why are you so eager to have this information? What would you do if you had it? I believe there is no reliable way to get it. Easy guess would be that the logins are made from the Netherlands, right? Does it really matter? Securing the account should be priority number one.

Comment: We just want to know and confirm it was them, We have a lot of other good evidence/coincidences, but being 100% sure is important. These are people he’s known for many years. So it’s a pretty crappy situation.

Comment: It's a stretch but according to makeuseof (https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/can-officially-browse-facebook-tor/) it is possible to connect to facebook through the Tor network. If either Tor, VPN or some other sort of proxy was used the results you get will be misleading.
Although, running the IP address that you uncover in Shodan (https://www.shodan.io/) could give you some interesting info.

Answer (score 1):

Let me split your question into three different questions.

> Is there a way they can hide their IP address?

Yes it's possible to hide your real address from other people or companies. You just need to use a VPN and switch to your desired location. It's that simple. If you want to read more about VPNs I got an interesting article [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/bb742566(v=technet.10))

> Does Facebook only show most used IP addresses?

No, Facebook lists all logins chronologically. You just need to login and navigate into the settings. After that go to "Your Facebook Information" > "Access your information" > "Security and Login Information" > "Logins and Logouts" now you can navigate down and on the last entry you will see a list of all logins. Maybe [this](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10152335613739275) helps you.

**Note:** I think you can't find the full log because you are only at *Security and Login* but there is only a list of currently logged in devices!

> How can we find out for sure?

If you find different IP addresses and login timestamps in this log you will know that you didn't log yourself in. Maybe you could look up these IP addresses and see that it's not even in your country, but don't trust it. As mentioned before it's possible to use a VPN to make it look like the IP is from your location.

Comment: The VPN article is 10 years old and is very technical (and for configuring Win 2000).

Comment: That's true but I would say this is a technical forum and for this guys it's a good information about what a VPN does - even if it's 10 years old. The basics haven't changed.

Comment: 1) The asker is clearly not technical 2) no it is not good information about how a VPN works *in the way that you describe in your answer* (there are *numerous* alternatives) 3) the basics have changed, especially when the article lists "Using a dial-up line to connect a branch office to a corporate LAN."

Comment: I understand what a VPN is, I’ll look at the article and try to find additional info on it as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The **first** thing you should do is **change your password**. Then, to investigate the IP addresses:

1. Top right, down-arrow > Settings , in the left-hand pane choose
   Security and login. Hover your mouse over the location to get the IP
   addresses.
2. Use a whois service such as https://www.whois.net/ to see if the IP address is from your ISP / country if it is a desktop session.
   You can now determine if a VPN is being used even if the location appears as US.

Either way, the next step should be to **Logout of all sessions** by clicking the link. Followed by preferably enabling 2fa authentication.